# How to include android-support-design in Android.mk file

Tags: android, android-ndk, android-support-design

I am trying to use `android-support-design` library ( because i have used FAB .which is from support design library) for one of my applications. I tried to build it with below Android.mk

```
LOCAL_PATH:= $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE_TAGS := optional

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(call all-java-files-under, src)


LOCAL_STATIC_JAVA_LIBRARIES := android-support-v4
LOCAL_STATIC_JAVA_LIBRARIES += android-support-v7-appcompat
LOCAL_STATIC_JAVA_LIBRARIES += android-support-design-res

LOCAL_RESOURCE_DIR := $(LOCAL_PATH)/res frameworks/support/v7/appcompat/res frameworks/support/design/res
LOCAL_PACKAGE_NAME := TestApp

LOCAL_AAPT_FLAGS := \
    --auto-add-overlay \
    --extra-packages android.support.v7.appcompat \
    --extra-packages android.support.design
include $(BUILD_PACKAGE)
```

But i always get this error:

```
make: *** No rule to make target `out/target/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/android-support-design-res_intermediates/javalib.jar', needed by `out/target/common/obj/APPS/TestApp/classes-full-debug.jar'.  Stop.
```

Can someone help me on this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I also met the same problem .

Maybe your mk is wrong.

I solve this problem .

One way:

```
mmm frameworks/support/design/
mmm your app
```

Other way:

use **make** command

eg.

```
make -j4 TestApp
```

---

my Android.mk is

```
LOCAL_PATH:= $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_STATIC_JAVA_LIBRARIES := android-support-v4 android-support-design android-support-v7-appcompat
LOCAL_MODULE_TAGS := optional
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := \
$(call all-java-files-under, src)
LOCAL_RESOURCE_DIR := $(LOCAL_PATH)/res \
frameworks/support/v7/appcompat/res \
frameworks/support/design/res
LOCAL_PACKAGE_NAME := MyDemo
LOCAL_CERTIFICATE := platform
LOCAL_PRIVILEGED_MODULE := true
LOCAL_AAPT_FLAGS := \
--auto-add-overlay \
--extra-packages android.support.design \
--extra-packages android.support.v7.appcompat
include $(BUILD_PACKAGE)
```

Answer (score 0):

My Demo app include Android support library and leakcanary

```
LOCAL_PATH:= $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_PROGUARD_ENABLED := disabled
#LOCAL_PROGUARD_FLAG_FILES := proguard.flags

LOCAL_MODULE_TAGS := optional


LOCAL_STATIC_JAVA_LIBRARIES := \
commonData-support-v4 \
dpt-haha-2.0.2 \
dpt-leakcanary-analyzer-1.4-beta2 \
dpt-leakcanary-watcher-1.4-beta2 \



LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(call all-java-files-under, src)

LOCAL_STATIC_JAVA_AAR_LIBRARIES:= \
    commonData-recyclerview-v7 \
    commonData-appcompat-v7 \
    commonData-design \
    commonData-cardview-v7 \
    dpt-leakcanary-android-1.4-beta2


 LOCAL_PACKAGE_NAME := AndroidAARDependDemo

LOCAL_AAPT_FLAGS := --auto-add-overlay \
--extra-packages android.support.v7.recyclerview \
--extra-packages android.support.design \
--extra-packages android.support.v7.cardview \
--extra-packages android.support.v7.appcompat \
--extra-packages com.squareup.leakcanary \


LOCAL_CERTIFICATE := platform

include $(BUILD_PACKAGE)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)


LOCAL_PREBUILT_STATIC_JAVA_LIBRARIES := \
    commonData-support-v4:libs/android-support-v4.jar \
    commonData-appcompat-v7:libs/appcompat-v7-23.2.1.aar \
    commonData-recyclerview-v7:libs/recyclerview-v7-23.2.1.aar \
    commonData-design:libs/design-23.2.1.aar \
    commonData-cardview-v7:libs/cardview-v7-23.2.1.aar \
    dpt-leakcanary-android-1.4-beta2:libs/leakcanary-android-1.4-    beta2.aar \
    dpt-haha-2.0.2:libs/haha-2.0.2.jar \
    dpt-leakcanary-analyzer-1.4-beta2:libs/leakcanary-analyzer-1.4-beta2.jar \
    dpt-leakcanary-watcher-1.4-beta2:libs/leakcanary-watcher-1.4-beta2.jar \


  include $(BUILD_MULTI_PREBUILT)
```